# NSUInteger on 64 and 32 bit architectures

Tags: objective-c

I implemented the [FNV1a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) hashing algorithm as follows:

```
#import "SWBHashAlgorithm.h"

@implementation SWBHashAlgorithm
- (NSUInteger)hashValues:(NSString *)values withSalt:(NSString *)salt {
    const NSUInteger FnvPrime = 16777619;
    const NSUInteger FnvOffsetBasis = 2166136261;

    NSMutableString *input = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [input appendString:values];
    if (salt != nil && ![salt isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        [input appendString:salt];
    }
    NSUInteger hash = FnvOffsetBasis;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i != [input length]; ++i) {
        hash = (hash ^ [input characterAtIndex:i]) * FnvPrime;
    }
    return hash;
}

@end
```

On x86_64 architecture, my unit test passes:

```
- (void)testSomeData {
    // Arrange

    // Act
    NSUInteger result = [self.hashAlgorithm hashValues:@"value1value2" withSalt:@"salt"];

    // Assert
    XCTAssertEqual(result, 4989295659699749532); }
```

But on i386 it fails because:

> SWBHashAlgorithmTests.m:36: ((result) equal to (4989295659699749532))
>   failed: ("3553444508") is not equal to ("4989295659699749532"): 33
>   NSUInteger result = [self.hashAlgorithm hashValues:@"value1value2"
>   withSalt:@"salt"]; 34      35     // Assert 36
>   XCTAssertEqual(result, 4989295659699749532);
>          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 37 } 38

How do I get the same value in 32 bit architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NS(U)Integer has different type declarations in 32/64 bit environment.

From the 64-Bit Transition Guide

> The most notable of these changes is that NSInteger and NSUInteger (Cocoa data types) are 64-bit in a 64-bit environment and 32-bit in a 32-bit environment.

To get the same result in both environments use a fixed size like `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`

Comment: Thank you very much! That was fast.